# Using vim / vimperator key bindings in Midori

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

I have recently been struggling to find a good lightweight browser with Vim keybindings that will run on Debian Linux (wheezy).  Dwb crashes all the time, Luakit is very old, Chromium has memory issues and the vim extensions (cVim/Vimium) don't work when pages are loading / on system pages, etc.

Midori seems like a good choice but I can't get the Vim bindings to work.  There are two options that appear on the net:

- [VimNav](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95998) user script - but I put this in .local/share/midori/scripts and nothing happens.  Midori functions as before.
- [Midorator](https://github.com/dev-random/midorator) - a plugin that claims to provide Vimperator style key bindings.  I haven't tried to compile it yet as it's very old, back from 2010, and hence seems unlikely to work with current Midori / WebKit.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I found this: http://www.fdn.fr/~arenevier/midori/ but can not access the script (connection timed out, may be my fault though). I'm curious you try midorator !

Comment: Thanks. Yes, userscripts.org seems to have been down for several days.  Ok, if I get the chance, will try to compile midorator.  Still hoping for more possibilities though :)